# Keras Image classification model working perfectly in Spyder but classifying only one class on Streamlit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, streamlit

**Objective :** To create a web app where anyone can use an Image CT scan to check whether someone has pneumonia or not

**Expected Result:** To classify classes correctly when a new image is used

```
 rslt
 Out[37]: array([[0.27656645, 0.7234335 ]], dtype=float32)
```

**Actual Result :** After loading the same model in Streamlit for every image it is showing the same probability for only one class. It is classifying as class '0' for every single image

```
0.9999     0.0001
```

Here's a video for the issue : [streamlit issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zh3oueDLJKo)

The codes and files are kept here : [Training_Testing_Data,Model,Streamlit_Code,Sample_image](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1z3lfVrVjmT8hic6DcGkBDatTSIlU1Lsj?usp=sharing)

Comment: when you use exactly the same model and the same image - what the predicted probabilities?

Comment: @theletz , When I use the same model and weights it is giving me same results for multiple images when I am using streamlit , when I am using an IDE its working fine. Please take a look at the video attached.